# Mongodb design for the subscription model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on an application where the user should be able to subscribe to the 3 levels of news letter. The three levels are

> 1. Project
> 2. Sub-Project
> 3. Component

I have separate collections approach in my mind, like this:

**Project Collection**

- Id
- ProjectName

**SubProject collection**

- Id
- SubprojectName
- ProjectId

**Component Collection**

- Id
- ComponentName
- SubProjectId

**User Collection**

- Id
- Username
- Subscription

  - Projects: [Array of project ids]
  - SubProjects: [Array of sub-project ids]
  - Components: [Array of component ids]

I'm not able to get the better approach on using embedding documents as Mongodb suggests. Having 4 different collections is kind of head ache and have to write more logic to workaround for joins.

Point to be noted here is, for instance, an user can subscribe to the `sub-project`, might not subscribed to the `project`.

The use case would be to retrieve the list of user's subscriptions, adding more subscriptions for the user and updating the subscription of the user.

Kindly suggest your views and ideas from your experience.

Comment: Just because you can embed , it is not always a good idea to do so. Think of embedding as a shortcut for linking for "one-to-very-few" relations only. I have written [a blog post on "over embedding"](http://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb/), which you might find interesting.